# Removing ListView Item - Android

Tags: java, android, listview

I am working on a app that puts some items in a list, then using a `DialogFragment` with the list of added items.

I would give the option to remove these items, the problem is there.

I declared in `OnItemClickListener` that the item should be removed when clicked, the item is removed from the list normally, but soon after an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` bursts, it looks like a silly error but I am not finding where the problem is, the try catch block does not raise exception. 
I am a student and I do not have much experience with android, so if they can give simple answers would help me a lot.

these are my codes:

DIALOG FRAGMENT
the dialog opens normally and the list is displayed

```java
public static class AlertDialogMyItems extends DialogFragment{

        MyAdapter adapter;
        ListView lvMyItems;        
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            ...

            lvMyItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                    Item item = (Item)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    adapter.removeItem(item);
                }
            });
           ...           
        }
    }
```

ADAPTER METHOD
item is removed from list and method finishes without problems

```java
     ...     
        public void removeItem(Item item){

            for(Item i:items)               
                if(i.getIdItem()==item.getIdItem())         
                   items.remove(i);     
        }
```

ERROR
The error happens right after returning to DialogFragment

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
  at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
  at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3503)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4310)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:669)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:675)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:783)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: have you called notifyDataSetChanged() after removing item?

Comment: Can u add some more adapter code

Comment: Thanks @H4SN , this was the problem!

Comment: your items were out of sync with adapter :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is why another pair of eyes is awesome!
ListView has an array of items, and you are trying to remove items from an array of the item, which is not an array, hence the error. What you would need to do for that is:

```
    public void removeItem(Item item){     
               items.remove();     
    }
```

But even better and more efficient is:

public static class AlertDialogMyItems extends DialogFragment{

```
    MyAdapter adapter;
    ListView lvMyItems;        
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        ...

        lvMyItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                Item item = (Item)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                item.remove(); // here is the change in code
            }
        });
       ...           
    }
}
```

and then you could remove this part of the code:

```
public void removeItem(Item item){     
           items.remove();     
}
```

Because it is a bit redundant.

Comment: I had tried this way at another time, the error persisted. I forgot to call notifyDataSetChanged(), but thanks so much for the help!